Keep trailing spaces when writing to file organization line sequential
I'm using GnuCOBOL and writing to a file, organization is line sequential, and I need to keep trailing spaces. Line sequential appends the [CR][LF] characters, but does so after removing trailing spaces.
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. TRAILING-SPACES.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT OUTFILE 
           ASSIGN 'O:\BATCH_JOBS\TMP\TRAILING-SPACES.COBOL.TXT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD OUTFILE
           DATA RECORD IS OUT-RECORD.

       01 OUT-RECORD.
          05 STUFF PIC X(5).

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTFILE.

           MOVE 'ABCDE' TO STUFF.
           WRITE OUT-RECORD.

           MOVE 'ABC  ' TO STUFF.
           WRITE OUT-RECORD.

           CLOSE OUTFILE.
           STOP RUN.

The output is
ABCDE[CR][LF]
ABC[CR][LF]
How would I get the output to be
ABCDE[CR][LF]
ABC[SPACE][SPACE][CR][LF]
I tried declaring the file as organization is sequential and generate the [CR][LF] but I can't seem to get it to work.
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. TRAILING-SPACES.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT OUTFILE 
           ASSIGN 'O:\BATCH_JOBS\TMP\TRAILING-SPACES.COBOL.TXT'
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD OUTFILE
           DATA RECORD IS OUT-RECORD.

       01 OUT-RECORD.
          05 STUFF PIC X(5).
          05 CR PIC X(1) VALUE X'0D'.
          05 LF PIC X(1) VALUE X'0A'.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTFILE.

           MOVE 'ABCDE' TO STUFF.
           WRITE OUT-RECORD.

           MOVE 'ABC  ' TO STUFF.
           WRITE OUT-RECORD.

           CLOSE OUTFILE.
           STOP RUN.

The output is
ABCDE[NUL][NUL]ABC[SPACE][SPACE][NUL][NUL]
Thanks everyone!

Just guessing as I have not used COBOL for nearly 35 years, but according to the docs:
When reading a "LINE SEQUENTIAL" file, records in excess of the size implied by the
file’s description in the "FILE SECTION" will be truncated while records shorter than
that size will be padded to the right with "SPACES" - so in your case, when the record is read back, it will contain trailing spaces.

I haven't touched COBOL in 30 years, too. You are absolutely right, and I would expect COBOL to do just that: if the buffer is too small then truncate, and if the buffer is too big then pad. What has me scratching my head is why writing to a file causes it to remove trailing spaces. In other languages, let's just choose C#, outfile.writeline("Hi, bdcoder              "); would include the spaces. It would not have side-effects or do anything fancy ... it would just do what you told it to do. But thank you kindly for commenting and sharing!

       01 OUT-RECORD.
          05 STUFF PIC X(5).
          05 CR PIC X(1) VALUE X'0D'.
          05 LF PIC X(1) VALUE X'0A'.

These VALUE clauses are ignored in the FILE SECTION.
There are several ways to adjust for that, but the easiest is to place the code in the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 OUT-RECORD PIC X(7).

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 WS-OUT-RECORD.
          05 STUFF PIC X(5).
          05 CR PIC X(1) VALUE X'0D'.
          05 LF PIC X(1) VALUE X'0A'.

Then
           MOVE "ABC" TO STUFF
           WRITE OUT-RECORD FROM WS-OUT-RECORD


That's not literally true. The VALUE clauses just don't change the initial memory content (and per standard the memory is only defined to be available after a successful OPEN, too).
They are totally used for INITIALIZE OUT-RECORD ALL TO VALUE, which could be used after the OPEN.
... but the main point "they are not (automatically) in the memory, it is clearer to use WS and  WRITE FROM" is definitely correct.

Oh, that's why! I did not know "variables" in FD and those in working-storage are handled differently. I just thought that variables are variables are variables (minding the scoping rules). In C, for example, you can declare a variable practically anywhere. Rick and Simon: thank you both for you insightful and extremely helpful responses!

ORGANIZATION LINE SEQUENTIAL was standardized in COBOL2023 and in the meantime several implementations did it different.
For that the general rules for WRITE specify:

For a line sequential file with a file description entry not  containing a RECORD clause with the DEPENDING phrase, any spaces to the right of the rightmost non-space character are not transferred to  file-name-1.

GnuCOBOL follows the standard by default but allows you to tweak the behaviour, see the manual under "Appendix I Runtime configuration, File IO" (or your runtime config runtime.cfg, see cobcrun --runtime-config to check where it resides):
Environment name:  COB_LS_FIXED
  Parameter name:  ls_fixed
         Purpose:  Defines if LINE SEQUENTIAL files should be fixed length
                   (or variable, by removing trailing spaces)
           Alias:  STRIP_TRAILING_SPACES  (0 = yes)
            Type:  boolean
         Default:  false
            Note:  This setting is most useful if you want to REWRITE those
                   files.
         Example:  LS_FIXED TRUE

Environment name:  COB_LS_VALIDATE
  Parameter name:  ls_validate
         Purpose:  Defines for LINE SEQUENTIAL files that the data should be
                   validated as it is read (status 09) / written (status 71).
            Type:  boolean
         Default:  true (per COBOL 2022)
            Note:  If active effectively disables COB_LS_NULLS.
         Example:  LS_VALIDATE FALSE

Environment name:  COB_LS_NULLS
  Parameter name:  ls_nulls
         Purpose:  Defines for LINE SEQUENTIAL files what to do with data
                   which is not DISPLAY type.  This could happen if a LINE
                   SEQUENTIAL record has BINARY/COMP data fields in it.
            Type:  boolean
         Default:  false
            Note:  The TRUE setting will insert a null character x"00" before
                   those values to escape them, and redo on read-in plus
                   validating that they only occur after a null character.
                   Decreases LINE SEQUENTIAL performance and prevents writing
                   escape sequences or formatting within the data.
                   Only checked if COB_LS_VALIDATE is disabled.
         Example:  LS_NULL = TRUE

Environment name:  COB_LS_SPLIT
  Parameter name:  ls_split
         Purpose:  Defines for LINE SEQUENTIAL files what to do when a record
                   is longer than the program handles. If 'ls_split=true' then
                   the data is returned as multiple records with io status 06,
                   otherwise the record is truncated, io status set to 04 and
                   the file skips to the next LF.
            Type:  boolean
         Default:  true (per COBOL 2022)
         Example:  LS_SPLIT = FALSE

If you want to globally change that, edit your runtime.cfg (or, commonly better, create an own one) to include
ls_fixed = true
ls_split = false

as an alternative: just put that into the environment
SET COB_LS_FIXED=1
SET COB_LS_SPLIT=0

or do that from the COBOL program before handling the file:
SET ENVIRONMENT "COB_LS_FIXED" TO "1"
SET ENVIRONMENT "COB_LS_SPLIT" TO "0"

But keep in mind that this will then also happen if you have huge record lengths.
It therefore is likely better to adjust your file description entry instead (and possibly get rid of the not-any-more standard DATA RECORD which is already duplicated by the record below the FD):
       FD OUTFILE
           RECORD IS VARYING IN SIZE FROM 1 TO 5 BYTES
           DEPENDING ON OUTFILE-LEN.

with
    77  OUTFILE-LEN PIC 99 COMP-5 VALUE LENGTH OF OUT-RECORD.

in WORKING-STORAGE SECTION (pre-set to 5 in your example, but you could also specify that before the WRITE). Note: the length will be auto-set on READ to whatever is found in the file.
This should also be more portable to other COBOL environments.

Wow! Thank you, Simon, for the education. It worked! I made the changes you suggested in FD and added the 77 level. With your suggestions implemented but without setting the environment variables, the truncation continued, but with the variables (and the FD and 77) it worked fine. I'm running GnuCOBOL 3.2.0 and it does not like BYTES in the FD. It complains with "error: 'BYTES' is a reserved word, but isn't supported"; I replaced it with CHARACTERS. I humbly thank you again for your insight and for sharing your experience with us.
